# Loop infinito com "While not Cds.Eof do"

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Tenho um `while not Eof` normal num *ClientDataSet*.
O único detalhe é no *AfterScroll*, onde edito o *dataset* em questão e dou um *post* no mesmo. Quando o **Eof** é ***True***, após o *post* ele altera para ***False***. Depurando a situação, percebi que internamente o *ClientDataSet* chama a rotina *Resync*, que por sua vez, chama a rotina *ActivateBuffers*, e esta por fim, altera o controle ***FEOF*** para ***False***. Nesse ponto, continuo no último registro do meu *ClientDataSet*, porém ele entende que não está no *Eof*.

Como posso resolver isso? É um *bug* do Delphi?

Código:

```
Cds.First;  
While not Cds.Eof do  
begin  
  Sleep(10);//Exemplo  
  Cds.Next;  
end;
```

AfterScroll

```
Cds.Edit;  
Cds.FieldByName('QTDE').AsFloat := 10;  
Cds.Post;
```

No AfterScroll, quando está EOF, após o Post o EOF retorna para False.

Comment: Se ele esta posicionado no ultimo registro então não é EOF.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Você tem razão, me expressei errado (Desculpe). Mas após o *Cds.Next*, entra no *AfterScroll* e nesse momento já está como **EOF**, o problema é que após o post no CDS, o **EOF** é alterado para ***False***.

Comment: Andrey, posta seu código :)

Comment: Pelo o que você falou, ele reposiciona o ponteiro no último registro e isso confunde a lógica que você usou em seu fluxo. Eu acho que você precisa alterar esse fluxo ou essa lógica.

Comment: Pessoal, descobri com a ajuda do @ReginaldoRigo. Realmente era problema de lógica. Por já estar como EOF, não havia registro selecionado, quando era dado Edit/Post, retornava para o último registro válido, mas o EOF realmente deixava de ser True. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda dos comentários do Reginaldo, cheguei a uma solução.
No *AfterScroll*, antes de executar o *Edit / Post*, faço um *if*, verificando se o *dataset* não está como **EOF**.

```
if not Cds.Eof then
begin
  Cds.Edit;  
  Cds.FieldByName('QTDE').AsFloat := 10;  
  Cds.Post;
end;
```

Dessa forma, ele apenas executará o Edit / Post enquanto houver um registro sendo visualizado no DataSet.